# Broken CSS when changing from blog.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/blog

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

We created a new URL for our site. The old URL was blog.mysite.com. The new URL is www.mysite.com/blog. The issue I am having is that while the css works fine on blog.mysite.com, it does not work on www.mysite.com/blog. The new url is looking for the files at www.mysite.com/wp-content... while the files are actually located at www.mysite.com/blog/wp-content... on the new URL (blog.mysite.com/wp-content... on the old one). Both point to the same server and the same files. Here is an example:

```html
<link href="/wp-content/themes/edition/prefix_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/wp-content/themes/edition/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Right? So update the href's to the right URL?

Answer (score 1):

Like @JonStirling said you should update your href attribute. The reason that it worked on blog.mysite.com is that it's a subdomain rather the new url.
The best way is to add the domain dynamically using `bloginfo()`, so your code will become something similar:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/prefix_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this way the path to the file will be loaded properly every time and it doesn't matter if it's on subdomain or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Wordpress it is advised to use the queueing systems WP offers. If you use it correctly you can do a lot of "tricks" with it - that is (almost) impossible with hardcoded stylesheet links and scripts.

Use the [wp_head()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) function - that can invoke a lot of things for you: for example [enqueued stylesheets](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) (or [scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)).

So I think you should change your code to the following

```
// Put this code in your functions.php
function enqueue_stylesheets() {

    // enqueueing prefix_css.css for all media, with a version number of 1.0.0
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'prefix_css',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/prefix_css.css',
        array(),
        '1.0.0',
        'all'
    );

    // enqueueing header.css for all media, with a version number of 1.0.0; AFTER prefix_css.css
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'header',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/header.css',
        array( 'prefix_css' ),
        '1.0.0',
        'all'
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheets' );
```

Remove the hard-coded stylesheet links from the head, and then change your header:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- everything that's in the header -->
    <?php
        wp_head();
    ?>
    </head>
<!-- continuing with the <body> -->
```

This will output your stylesheets and respect the URL structure of the site.

Of course, you can use [bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/), but the best practice is to use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) instead.